# Paypal Angular get shipping address

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, paypal, ngx-paypal

I am using ngx-paypal from: https://github.com/Enngage/ngx-paypal

A regular workflow for a simple payment works. But I need to get shipping address after authorization.

If I add `onShippingChange` callback - I get the address but the workflow stalls - the paypal checkout window shows waiting and `onClientAuthorization` is never called.

**What am I supposed to do in the callback so the workflow can resume?**

```
onShippingChange: (data, actions) => {
  // ??
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the onShippingChange function for this. In onApprove, there is a `data` parameter.

Log it. Examine the entire object.

Comment: i did. there is payer address but not shipping address.. also when you dont have onShippingChange - the paypal checkout window does not offer the payer any way to select the delivery address.. so it is right thing to to have onShippingChange

Comment: The payer address is their shipping address. They can select that delivery address without onShippingChange.

Comment: idk abt that but on my sandbox i got 2 different addresses where shipping address is a correct one and the payer address is just a country code and nothing else there.. also payers might have multiple addresses. i for example have 2. my main address is not where i ship my purchases to.. *They can select that delivery address without onShippingChange* - thats not what i see on the screen..

Comment: By default, unless you are overriding the shipping preference in application_context, buyers can select a shipping address during checkout. And that address should be returned in the onApprove's first parameter. If you're doing non-default things then I can't speak to that

Answer (score 1):

the correct way to deal with shipping change:

```
onShippingChange: (data, actions) => {
  return actions.resolve() // or .reject()
},
```

Comment: Best simply not use the onShippingChange callback here; it is unnecessary and will slow your checkout. But yes for situations that do call for it, the function must return a Promise (already resolved or not)

Comment: no I need/want/have to use it. it gives me more precise control over the checkout. thanks for trying to help but the question is answered and the checkout process is not part of it..

Comment: "I need to get shipping address after authorization"  onShippingChange is not the answer to this, which is what your question seeks. It exists for other purposes. If you need it for those other purposes, great. Nothing to do with your question, though.

Comment: no question was what to write in the callback function... you are on in contrast trying to get into my code business logic which is **my** business logic  and there is nothing to discuss.. could you please stop?

Comment: I'm not telling you or those reading this what to do. I'm clarifying what onShippingChange is for. It's not for getting the shipping address.

Comment: [BoppityBop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347484/boppity-bop), I also have the same implementation as you and it works. For some reason there seems to be disconnect in packages as I couldn't get the address from onApprove.